# Why I get error 404 in bcrypt when I run npm install?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, bcrypt

Im trying to run `sudo npm install` in my project and I got the next error: 
`Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`

Im using 10.15.3 node version and 6.4.1 npm version.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you on windows, mac, linux?

Comment: On linux @JoshuaTerrill

Comment: It might be that it doesn't like you running sudo, you may have to run the install command with  the unsafe-perm command: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the node modules file. Then install `bcrypt` by manually using `sudo npm i bcrypt --save`.
Then run the command `sudo npm i`.

If this is not working try it without `sudo` command.

Answer (score 3):

As it look to be a problem with node gyp. First install `build-essential` in linux.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After that you need to install `python-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

That is it, now you need reinstall your `bcrypt` package.